# tree data structure with list in c++

Tags: c++, list, tree, self-reference

I implemented a tree structure in c++, referring to other people's codes. The code below I made was surely compiled and seem to work well. But I suspect that there are better ways. For example, is this code safe in the point of memory leak? Is there any simpler and computationally more efficient way?

Specifically, I doubt the necessity of the "std::list lst_nodes".
The expand_node function in Tree class attaches a new node to a parent node the value of which is closest to that of the new node. This process requires iteration over all the existing nodes to access their values. For this iteration purpose, I defined a member variable named "std::list lst_nodes" in Tree class. And I susplect there may exists a neat way to do the same without defining lst_nodes.

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

class Node{
  public:/*functions*/
    Node(const double& val_, Node* parent_=nullptr)
      :val(val_), parent(parent_)
    {
      if(parent){
        parent->children.push_back(this);
      }
    }
  public:/*variables*/
    Node* parent;
    std::list<Node*> children;
    double val;
};

class Tree{
  public:/*function*/
    Tree(double x_init);
    void extend_node();

  public:/*variables*/
    list<Node*> lst_nodes;
    double x_init;
};

Tree::Tree(double x_init_)
  :x_init(x_init_)
{
  Node* n=new Node(x_init);
  lst_nodes.push_back(n);
}

void Tree::extend_node(){
  double val_new = rand();
  auto it=lst_nodes.begin();
  double minval = abs((**it).val-val_new);
  Node* node_parent;
  for(;it!=lst_nodes.end(); it++){
    if(minval>abs((**it).val-val_new)){
      minval = abs((**it).val-val_new);
      node_parent = *it;
    }
  }
  Node* n_new = new Node(val_new, node_parent);
  node_parent->children.push_back(n_new);
  lst_nodes.push_back(n_new);
}

int main(){
  Tree t(0);
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    t.extend_node();
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can post over on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well

Comment: @Richard: your link doesn't appear as you intended, because you omitted the "https://"

Comment: *is this code safe in the point of memory leak?* -- There isn't a single call to `delete`, thus the code is full of memory leaks.

Comment: @Beta fixed thanks

Comment: You are correct, lst_nodes shouldn't be there.  You are creating both a list of Nodes and a Tree.  Instead make it a search tree so you can locate nodes that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern C++, you can use `unique_pointer<T>` instead of raw `T*` pointers when the object pointed to is owned by the object that has the pointer. This way, you don't have to explicitely `delete` the object, it will be done in the `unique_ptr` destructor.

In a tree (i.e a connected graph with no cycles in it) the ownership is clearly defined : every node owns its children, so you can use `list<unique_ptr<Node>>` for `Node::children`.